# Linux set min_rto on IPv6 device

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp

I came across https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210367/changing-the-tcp-rto-value-in-linux which pretty much does exactly what I want, but I need to do it with an IPv6 tunnel.

```
$ sudo ip -6 route
aaaa::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev wlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Then, if I look at my active connections we see:

```
$ ss -i
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                                                                             aaaa::1:51692

         cubic rto:360 rtt:157.424/6.438 ato:40 mss:64 cwnd:10 send 32.5Kbps pacing_rate 65.0Kbps rcv_space:28800
```

It currently has an rto of 360. This device **only deals withs super low bandwidth, high latency, lossy networks (i.e. 6LoWPaN)** so I want to increase the min_rto to at least several seconds.

I have disabled frto:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_frto
0
```

Now I want to set min_rto, as shown in the linked question.

```
$ sudo ip -6 route change aaaa:: dev tun0 rto_min 2000
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

**Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?**

It's worth noting that if I do 2000ms (or 5ms, as in the linked answer), it tells me it's an invalid value, hence why I dropped off the ms part. In case it matters, my Linux info is below:

```
Linux 4.4.13-v7+ #894 SMP Mon Jun 13 13:13:27 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @030 "Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?" (hint: it's bolded)

Answer (score 0):

The `tcp_*` settings listed under IPv4 also apply to IPv6, according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt).

> ```
> IPv6 has no global variables such as tcp_*.  tcp_* settings under ipv4/ also
> apply to IPv6 [XXX?].
> ```

Given the question in the documentation there, it would be wise to verify this applies to your specific (older) kernel before proceeding.

Comment: I believe they do, changing `ipv6/tcp_frto` has a noticeable impact on my ipv6 rto values